# On the password_confirm widget, how do I change the text of "Password"?

Tags: 8, hooks, i18n-l10n

By default, the password change form on the user account page looks like this:

- **Current password**
- **Password**
- **Confirm password**

This is bad usability because it is not clear to users that "Password" means "New password".

So I want to change the strings to this:

- **Current password**
- **New password**
- **Confirm new password**

Under interface translation, it's easy to change "Confirm password" to "Confirm new password" because that string is only used for the confirm password form.  However, I cannot change "Password" to "New password" using the translation interface because this is the same "Password" used on the user login form.

So, I tried to alter this in `hook_form_alter()` targeting the user account page, but  `$form['account']['pass']` does not contain the strings "Password" and "Confirm password":

[image: form-account-pass]

How do I change the text "Password" only on the Password Confirmation widget?